# write coordinates in the base of $1,x,x^2,x^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given this task and have no clue what to do.

We are given, linear space,which is spanned by polynomials (with real coefficients), whose degrees are at most 3, and we are give the polynomial $f(x) =2-3x+x^3$

How can I write $f(x)$ coordinates in the base $1,x,x^2,x^3$?

Comment: Can you write $2-3x+x^3$ as a linear combination of $1, x, x^2, x^3$?

Comment: Welcome to the website. Refer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick guide on Mathjax to typeset your Math equations in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, go back to basic definitions. What does it mean for the tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ to be the coordinates of a vector $\mathbf v$ relative to some ordered basis $\mathcal B=(\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_3,\mathbf v_4)$? It means that $\mathbf v$ can be expressed uniquely as the linear combination $a\mathbf v_1+b\mathbf v_2+c\mathbf v_3+d\mathbf v_4$, i.e., the coordinates of $\mathbf v$ relative to $\mathcal B$ are exactly the coefficients of the basis vectors in that unique linear combination.

Knowing this, what do you think the coordinates of the polynomial $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ relative to the ordered basis $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ are?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let the co-ordinates of $f(x)$ with respect to the (ordered) basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ be $(a,b,c,d)$. This means $f(x)=2-3x+x^3=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$. Now compare the coefficients of different powers of $x$ on each side.